# jQuery custom content scroller disappearing when I visit other pages

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress Theme that functions as one-page-app but I don't see any Angular libraries included anywhere.

I have managed to created a custom wordpress page template for the homepage that wasn't included in the theme. In this page I have a row with 3 scrollable columns using [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to replace the default browser's scrollbar.

When you visit the site, it will look as it should. But when you navigate to another page and then go back to homepage, the custom scrollbar stops displaying and it reverts back to the default one.

I don't see any errors in the console.

You can see a live version of the page here: http://utopic.vision/demo

I initialize the custom scrollbar by adding the class `mCustomScrollbar` to the section, like this.

```
<div class="row" style="height: 100% !important; margin-left: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important;">

    <div class="col-md-5 no-padder" style="overflow-y: hidden !important; height: 100% !important;">
        <section class="vbox animated fadeInUp">
            <section class="scrollable hover mCustomScrollbar">
                some data
            </section>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 no-padder" style="overflow-y: hidden !important; overflow: hidden !important; height: 100%;">
        <section class="vbox">
            <section class="scrollable hover mCustomScrollbar">
                some data
            </section>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 no-padder" style="overflow-y: hidden !important; height: 100%;">
        <section class="vbox">
            <section class="scrollable hover mCustomScrollbar">
                some data
            </section>
    </div>

</div>
```

And inside `functions.php` this is how the theme adds css and js libraries to the header. I added the custom scrollbar libraries manually at the end.

```
function musik_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'musik-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'musik-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'musik-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    wp_enqueue_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/animate.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('simple-line-icons', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/simple-line-icons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('app', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/app.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/font.css');
    **wp_enqueue_style('scrollbar', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css');**


    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/app.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_style('jplayer', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jPlayer/jplayer.flat.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('jplayer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jPlayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('playlist', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jPlayer/add-on/jplayer.playlist.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('storage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.storageapi.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('player',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/player.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('playlists',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/playlist.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    **wp_enqueue_script('scrollbar',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );**
    wp_localize_script('player', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )), '', true);

    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement', false, array('jquery'), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script('tile',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/masonry/tiles.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('tile-init',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/tile.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    if( get_theme_mod( 'hide-loading' ) == 0 ){
        wp_enqueue_script('nprogress',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/nprogress/nprogress.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_style('nprogress', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/nprogress/nprogress.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('pjax',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.pjax.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script('pjaxinit',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'musik_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

After a little digging I realized the theme is using [pAjax](http://georges.github.io/pajax/) plugin to achieve the one-page-app functionality (like Angular).

So all I had to do was re-initialize the custom scrollbar using jQuery (instead of HTML) in ajax.js which is a [pAjax](http://georges.github.io/pajax/) component.

Just added this to ajax.js which is responsible of making the ajax requests.

```
$(".scrollable .hover").mCustomScrollbar();
```